# Live update multiple Y-axis in plotly dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to read sensor values from raspberry pi sense hat and live plotting 3 sensor data on same y-axis and time on x-axis. But only one graph is visible out of 3. For this example I am using a random number generator for sensor values. How to show live data for all 3 values on y-axis? What am I doing wrong?

```
# from dash.dependencies import Output, Event
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque

# define a function to get CPU temperature data
def check_CPU_temp():
    a = random.randint(0,9)
    b = random.randint(0,9)
    c = random.randint(0,9)
    return a, b, c


X = deque(maxlen=50)
X.append(1)
acc_X = deque(maxlen=50)
acc_Y = deque(maxlen=50)
acc_Z = deque(maxlen=50)
a, b, c = check_CPU_temp()
acc_X.append(a)
acc_Y.append(b)
acc_Z.append(c)

def update_values(acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z):
    a1, b1, c1 = check_CPU_temp()
    acc_X.append(a1)
    acc_Y.append(b1)
    acc_Z.append(c1)
    return acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z 


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='refresh',
            interval=1 * 1000,
            n_intervals=0
            ),
        ]
)


@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'), [Input("refresh", "n_intervals")])


def update_graph_scatter(n_intervals):
    X.append(X[-1] + 1)
    update_values(acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z)
    data_x = go.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(acc_X),
            name='acc x',
            showlegend=True,
            mode= 'lines',
            yaxis='y'
            )
    data_y = go.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(acc_Y),
            name='acc y',
            showlegend=True,
            mode= 'lines',
            yaxis='y1'
            )
    data_z = go.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(acc_Z),
            name='acc z',
            showlegend=True,
            mode= 'lines',
            yaxis='y2'
            )
    layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X), max(X)],),
                       yaxis=dict(
                           range=[0, 10],
                           title='y'),
                       yaxis1=dict(
                           range=[0, 10],
                           side='right',
                           title='y1'),
                       yaxis2=dict(
                           range=[0, 10],
                           side='left',
                           title='y2'))

    return {'data': [data_x, data_y, data_z], 'layout': layout}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='192.168.1.16', port='8050')
```

[image: Output graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using fig.addtrace()

```
import dash
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from collections import deque
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()
sense.set_imu_config(True, True, True)  # accelerometer, magnetometer , gyroscope
sense.clear()

# define a function to get acceleration data
def check_acc_data():
    acc = sense.get_accelerometer_raw()
    return round(acc["x"],3), round(acc["y"],3), round(acc["z"],3)

def update_values(times, acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z):
    times.append(dt.strptime(str(dt.now()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
    a1, b1, c1 = check_acc_data()
    acc_X.append(a1)
    acc_Y.append(b1)
    acc_Z.append(c1)
    return times, acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z

times = deque(maxlen=50)
acc_X = deque(maxlen=50)
acc_Y = deque(maxlen=50)
acc_Z = deque(maxlen=50)
update_values(times, acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='example_graph', figure={}),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=250,
            n_intervals=0
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("example_graph", "figure"),
    [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')]
)

def update_figure(n):
    update_values(times, acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z)
    
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=list(times), y=list(acc_X), mode="lines+markers", name='Acc X'),
        secondary_y=False
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=list(times), y=list(acc_Y), mode="lines+markers", name='Acc Y'),
        secondary_y=True,
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=list(times), y=list(acc_Z), mode="lines+markers", name='Acc Z'),
        secondary_y=True,
    )

    # fig.update_yaxes(secondary_y=False)
    # fig.update_yaxes(secondary_y=True)
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[-2.5,2.5]),
                      yaxis1=dict(range=[-2.5,2.5]),
                      yaxis2=dict(range=[-2.5,2.5]))
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='192.168.1.16',port='8050')
```